# Why Hadoop Streaming cannot find my script?

Tags: perl, hadoop

I am streaming two scripts wordCountMap.pl and wordCountReduce.pl in Hadoop, which are supposed to count the occurrences of each word in a file.

But Hadoop kept complaining about wordCountMap.pl. My command and output are below.

Command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -input wordCount/words.txt -output output -mapper wordCount/wordCountMap.pl -file wordCount/wordCountMap.pl -reducer wordCount/wordCuntReduce.pl -file wordCount/wordCountReduce.pl
```

Output:

```
15/08/18 20:09:50 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
15/08/18 20:09:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
File: /home/hduser/wordCount/wordCountMap.pl does not exist, or is not readable.
Try -help for more information
Streaming Command Failed!
```

However wordCountMap.pl is good (to me), as I typed:

```
hadoop fs -cat wordCount/wordCountMap.pl
```

and got:

```
15/08/18 20:21:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    while(<STDIN>) {
        chomp;
        @words = split;
        foreach $w (@words) {
            $key = $w;
            $value = "1";
            print "$key\t$value\n";
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my command? (I think we can safely ignore the WARN message above.)

FYI, wordCountReduce.pl is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$count = 0;
while(<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    ($key,$value) = split "\t";

    if (!defined($oldkey)) {
        $oldkey = $key;
        $count  = $value;
    } else {
        if ($oldkey eq $key) {
        $count = $count + $value;
        } else {
        print "$oldkey\t$count\n";
        $oldkey = $key;
        $count  = $value;
        }
    }
}
print "$oldkey\t$count\n";
```

and words.txt

```
a a b
b c
a
```

and the result of "hadoop fs -ls wordCount" is

```
15/08/18 21:27:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup        145 2015-08-18 20:04 wordCount/wordCountMap.pl
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup        346 2015-08-18 20:04 wordCount/wordCountReduce.pl
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup         12 2015-08-18 20:04 wordCount/words.txt
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Keep the scripts in local file system

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the instructions carefully on the  http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file /home/hduser/mapper.py -mapper /home/hduser/mapper.py -file /home/hduser/reducer.py -reducer /home/hduser/reducer.py -input /user/hduser/gutenberg/* -output /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

there it clearly shows there is no need to copy the mapper.py and reducer.py to the HDFS, you can link both the files from the local filesystem: as /path/to/mapper. I am sure you can avoid the above error.

Comment: Can you please give the specific command that "link both the files from the local filesystem: as /path/to/mapper"? I actually saw this answer in another post, but I could not figure out how to do that.

Comment: Link to local file system did not work. I tested "hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -input words.txt -output output -mapper /path/to/wordCount -file /path/to/wordCountMap.pl -reducer /path/to/wordCountReduce.pl -file /path/to/wordCountReduce.pl" and Hadoop gave "15/08/19 00:48:30 ERROR streaming.PipeMapRed: configuration exception
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/path/to": error=13, Permission denied". But I did change chmod 777 /path/to. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I finally figured it out. The command should be: hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -input words.txt -output output -mapper wordCountMap.pl -file /local_path/to/wordCountMap.pl -reducer wordCountReduce.pl -file /local_path/to/wordCountReduce.pl.